# Nominal voltage of supercap

Tags: voltage, supercapacitor, capacity

Is it possible to replace a supercap e.g. an FCS0V224ZFTBR24 which is a 3.5 V type by its equivalent with a higher voltage (5.5 V), the FCS0H224ZFTBR24? The datasheet of both types is [here](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/212/1/KEM_S6011_FC-1104096.pdf).

What will be the results? The circuit will not be changed. Lower storage time?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to charge your supercapacitor to 3.5V (The circuit doesn't change otherwise) so the only way it will be effected is by giving you a higher voltage tolerance (for spikes and such).